# Hackerrank Lists Problem ~ Standard test case works but others don't

Tags: python-3.x, list

Consider a list (list = []). You can perform the following commands:

```
insert i e: Insert integer e at position .
print: Print the list.
remove e: Delete the first occurrence of integer e.
append e: Insert integer e at the end of the list.
sort: Sort the list.
pop: Pop the last element from the list.
reverse: Reverse the list.
```

Initialize your list and read in the value of  followed by  lines of commands where each command will be of the  types listed above. Iterate through each command in order and perform the corresponding operation on your list.

Sample Input:

```
12
insert 0 5
insert 1 10
insert 0 6
print
remove 6
append 9
append 1
sort
print
pop
reverse
print
```

My Code:

```
import sys

if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())

my_list = []
inputs  = []

for line in sys.stdin:
    inputs.append(line)

for item in inputs:
    if item[0:5] == 'print':
        print(my_list)
    elif item[0:2] == 'in':
        inserts = [s for s in item.split()][1:3]
        inserts = list(map(int, inserts))
        my_list.insert(inserts[0], inserts[1])
    elif item[0:3] == 'rem':
        inserts = list(map(int, [s for s in item.split()][1]))
        my_list.remove(inserts[0])
    elif item[0:2] == 'ap':
        inserts = list(map(int, [s for s in item.split()][1]))
        my_list.append(inserts[0])
    elif item[0:4] == 'sort':
        my_list.sort()
    elif item[0:3] == 'pop':
        my_list.pop()
    elif item[0:7] == 'reverse':
        my_list.reverse()
```

I'm not sure as to why my code is not getting approved upon submission. In this test case they provided, my code passes. 
The expected output is the following:

```
[6, 5, 10]
[1, 5, 9, 10]
[9, 5, 1]
```

Thanks so much for the help!

Comment: You read `N` from `stdin` but you never use it.  Is it possible that this leads to problems when the number of lines in the input stream is different from `N`?  (note that I haven't read the specs of the problem)

Comment: Honestly, I'm not sure if that matters. From what I can see, that shouldn't impact the outcome correct? The first number only denotes how many commands there could be.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your problem is that your append code has a bug when the number to be appended has more than one digit. In your code here

```
inserts = list(map(int, [s for s in item.split()][1]))
my_list.append(inserts[0])
```

for example if the "item" command was "append 12", `[s for s in item.split()][1]` would be the string "12", so `list(map(int, [s for s in item.split()][1]))` is mapping each character in that string to an integer, giving you [1, 2] rather than [12], and therefore `my_list.append(inserts[0])` would be appending the number 1 instead of 12. So fix that and you will fix your problem.

Comment: Thanks so much for this! This solved my issue. I appreciate the help.

Comment: inserts = list(map(int,[s for s in item.split()][1:])) strictly only a colon(:) needed to add. hence solved.

Answer (score 3):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
    m=list()
    for i in range(N):
       method,*l=input().split()
       k=list(map(int,l))
       if len(k)==2:
          q=[k[0]]
          w=[k[1]]
       elif len(k)==1:
          q=[k[0]]
       if method =='insert':
          m.insert(q[0],w[0])
       elif method == 'append':
          m.append(q[0])
       elif  method == 'remove':
          m.remove(q[0])
       elif method =='print':
          print(m)
       elif method == 'reverse':
          m.reverse()
       elif method =='pop':
          m.pop()
       elif method == 'sort':
          m.sort()
```

Comment: While this code may solve the question, [including an explanation](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/114762) of how and why this solves the problem would really help to improve the quality of your post, and probably result in more up-votes. Remember that you are answering the question for readers in the future, not just the person asking now. Please [edit] your answer to add explanations and give an indication of what limitations and assumptions apply.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a solution with no "if" or "elif" statements:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
    commands = {
        "insert": lambda x, y, z: x.insert(y, z),
        "print": lambda x: print(x),
        "remove": lambda x, y: x.remove(y),
        "append": lambda x, y: x.append(y),
        "sort": lambda x: x.sort(),
        "pop": lambda x: x.pop(),
        "reverse": lambda x: x.reverse(),
    }
    out = []
    for i in range(N):        
        a = input()
        split_a = a.split(' ')
        command = split_a[0]
        try:
            commands[command](out, int(split_a[1]), int(split_a[2]))
        except IndexError:
            try:
                commands[command](out, int(split_a[1]))
            except IndexError:
                commands[command](out)
```

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow and thanks for helping. Perhaps you could explain why removing the if and elif statements will help?

Comment: Thanks Tim. I personally try to avoid as many "if", and "elif" conditionals as possible because they tend to be overused. However, I use them when I have no choice.

In my experience, trying to find solutions without using "if", and "elif" helps me think differently and learn better approaches to certain problems.

Also, when it comes to unit testing your code, you may need to handle all conditions if possible when using conditionals. This question for example needs 7+ "if" and "elif" conditionals. With my approach, I only need to test 3 cases in my try excepts.

Comment: Thanks - your solution does feel more pythonic.

Answer (score 1):

```
def execute(lst, cmd, *args):
    if cmd == 'insert':
        lst.insert(int(args[0]), int(args[1]))
    elif cmd == 'print':
        print(lst)
    elif cmd == 'remove':
        lst.remove(int(args[0]))
    elif cmd == 'append':
        lst.append(int(args[0]))
    elif cmd == 'sort':
        lst.sort()
    elif cmd == 'reverse':
        lst.reverse()
    elif cmd == 'pop':
        lst.pop()
   else: 
        print("Command not recognized!")

lst = []
for _ in range(int(input())):
execute(lst, *input().split())
```

Answer (score 1):

```
N = int(input())
lst = []
for i in range(N):
    command = input().split()
    if command[0] == "print":
        print(lst)
    elif len(command) == 1:
        getattr(lst, command[0])()
    elif len(command) == 2:
        getattr(lst, command[0])(int(command[1]))
    else:
        getattr(lst, command[0])(int(command[1]), int(command[2]))
```

Comment: Very creative idea! I found that the later three elif/else cases could be simplified to `else: getattr(lst, command[0])(*map(int, command[1:]))`

Answer (score 0):

The string slicing is not a good idea. Also, you need to get user input N times. So you can edit your solution like below :

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
    the_list = list()

    for _ in range(N):
        query = input().split()
        if query[0] == "print":
            print(the_list)
        elif query[0] == "insert":
            the_list.insert(int(query[1]), int(query[2]))
        elif query[0] == "remove":
            the_list.remove(int(query[1]))
        elif query[0] == "append":
            the_list.append(int(query[1]))
        elif query[0] == "sort":
            the_list = sorted(the_list)
        elif query[0] == "pop":
            the_list.pop()
        elif query[0] == "reverse":
            the_list.reverse()
```

Comment: Why are we doing this "query = input().split()" ? I need to understand its purpose

Comment: @Rahul because we need to get the proper format of the user's input. Remember the user input is a string but we need the first word as a string but the others should be int to solve the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
N = int(input())
reqarr = []
for i in range(0,N):
    inplist = (input().split())
    if(inplist[0] == "insert" ):
        reqarr.insert(int(inplist[1]),int(inplist[2]))
    elif(inplist[0] == "print"):
        print(reqarr)
    elif(inplist[0] == "remove"):
        reqarr.remove(int(inplist[1]))
    elif(inplist[0] == "append"):
        reqarr.append(int(inplist[1])) 
    elif(inplist[0]=="sort"):
        reqarr.sort()   
    elif(inplist[0]=="reverse"):
        reqarr.reverse() 
    elif(inplist[0] == "pop"):
        reqarr.pop()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Though we thank you for your answer, it would be better if it provided additional value on top of the other answers. In this case, your answer does not provide additional value, since hevalhazalkurt already posted that solution. If a previous answer was helpful to you, you should vote it up once you have enough reputation.

Comment: Okay.I will try to do that from the next contributions

Answer (score 0):

```
def operation(last_value1,operation_name,*number):
    list_number = last_value1
    if operation_name.lower() == 'insert':
        list_number.insert(int(number[0]),int(number[1]))
    elif operation_name.lower() == 'remove':
        list_number.remove(int(number[0]))
    elif operation_name.lower() == 'append':
        list_number.append(int(number[0]))
    elif operation_name.lower() == 'sort':
        list_number = sorted(list_number)
    elif operation_name.lower() == 'print':
        print(list_number)
    elif operation_name.lower() == 'pop':
        list_number.pop()
    elif operation_name.lower() == 'reverse':
        list_number= list_number[::-1]
    return list_number

N = int(input())
last_value = []
for count in range(0,N):
        command_input = input("Please enter the command with number seperated by space")
        command_input = command_input.split()
        if len(command_input) == 3:
            last_value = operation(last_value,command_input[0],command_input[1],command_input[2])
        elif len(command_input) == 2:
            last_value= operation(last_value,command_input[0],command_input[1])
        else:
            last_value = operation(last_value,command_input[0])
```

Comment: Please don't post only code as answer, but also provide an explanation what your code does and how it solves the problem of the question. Answers with an explanation are usually more helpful and of better quality, and are more likely to attract upvotes.

Answer (score 0):

```
*if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
    the_list = list()
    
    for cmd in range(N):
        input_cmd = input().split()
        if input_cmd[0] == 'print':
            print(the_list)
        
        elif input_cmd[0] == 'insert':
            the_list.insert(int(input_cmd[1]), int(input_cmd[2]))
        
        elif input_cmd[0] == 'remove':
            the_list.remove(int(input_cmd[1]))
        
        elif input_cmd[0] == 'append':
            the_list.append(int(input_cmd[1]))
        
        elif input_cmd[0] == 'sort':
            the_list = sorted(the_list)
            
        elif input_cmd[0] == 'pop':
            the_list.pop()
        
        elif input_cmd[0] == 'reverse':
            the_list.reverse()*
```

Comment: While code only answers might help in a specific case, please provide detail on why and how this works, so that similar problems could be solved.

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    N = int(input())
    l=[]

    for i in range(N):
        s=input().split("\n")
        for j in s:
            m=j.split()
            if m[0]=="insert":
                l.insert(int(m[1]),int(m[2]))
            elif m[0]=="print":
                print(l)
            elif m[0]=="remove":
                l.remove(int(m[1]))
            elif m[0]=="append":
                l.append(int(m[1]))
            elif m[0]=="sort":
                l.sort()
            elif m[0]=="pop":
                l.pop()
            elif m[0]=="reverse":
                l.reverse()
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code-only answers are not recommended at all. Please add relevant details to your questions so other can also understand your answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
x= int(input())
lst = []
for i in range(x):
    n = input()
    lst.append(n)
newlist=[]
for ele in lst:
    splitted = ele.split()
    if splitted[0] == "insert":
        newlist.insert(int(splitted[1]),splitted[2])

    elif splitted[0] == "print":
        print(newlist)

    elif splitted[0] == "remove":
        newlist.remove(splitted[1])

    elif splitted[0] == "append":
        newlist.append(splitted[1])

    elif splitted[0] == "sort":
        newlist.sort()

    elif splitted[0] == "pop":
        newlist.pop()

    elif splitted[0] == "reverse":
        newlist.reverse()

    else:
        print("Command out of Scope")
```

Comment: It would help if you added a helpful comment about what you did to make the code work. Just code alone doesn't really help this person understand what they did wrong.

Answer (score 0):

```
### You can try this one:
if __name__ == '__main__':
    n = int(input())
    num_list = []
    for _ in range(n):
        string = input().split()
        command = string[0]
        args = string[1:]
        if command != "print":
            command += "(" + ",".join(args) + ")"
            eval("num_list." + command)
        else:
            print(num_list)
```